# moment to validate date and time with custom format

Tags: validation, momentjs

I'm trying to use moment to check if the  date/time presented is valid. I'm interested in validating dates in the following format:

```
10/10/2016 20:45
```

I've tried using this code, but the date is always considered invalid:

```
moment("10/10/2016 20:45", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm", true);
```

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

thanks.

Luis

Comment: You have `2045` in the input string, while you have `HH:mm` in the format, the problem is the `:`, change the input to `20:45` or the format to `HHmm`

Comment: @VincenzoC: You should post that as an answer to the question.

Comment: @nyedidikeke you're right, I've added my answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that was a typo...It's still not working...

Comment: Working now...d vs D...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `2045` in the input string, while you have `HH:mm` in the format, the problem is the `:`, change the input to `20:45` or the format to `HHmm`.

Moreover the token for day is the uppercase `DD` instead of the lowercase `dd`, see docs [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Here a working example:

```js
var m1 = moment("10/10/2016 2045", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm", true);
var m2 = moment("10/10/2016 2045", "DD/MM/YYYY HHmm", true);
var m3 = moment("10/10/2016 20:45", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", true);
console.log(m1.isValid()); // false
console.log(m2.isValid()); // true
console.log(m3.isValid()); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```