# How to check date format validation with moment

Tags: typescript, momentjs

My question is regarding the validation of the format in which dates are entered. I want `true` if and only if the date is entered exactly in this format, **MM-DD-YYYY**. But my code simply validates dates with **/** (i.e. with slash) also. This means `02-29/2020`, `01/30-2020` and even mix format like `02/-29-/2020` is also `true`. Also days, months and years have to be in 2 digit and 4 digit format respectively. I took help from:
[moment to validate date and time with custom format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210785/moment-to-validate-date-and-time-with-custom-format). I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qylgb2) also. Here's my code:

```
validate(sDate: string, eDate: string) {
  this.isValidDate = true;
  this.startInvalid = false;
  this.endInvalid = false;
  this.dateErrors = new Set<string>();
  const fromDate = moment(sDate, "MM-DD-YYYY");
  console.log(fromDate.isValid());
  const toDate = moment(eDate, "MM-DD-YYYY");
  const currentDate = moment();
  if (fromDate.isAfter(toDate)) {
      this.dateErrors.add('Errors.StartDateMoreThanEndDate');
      this.startInvalid = true;
      this.isValidDate = false;
  }
    console.log(this.dateErrors);
    return this.isValidDate;
}
```

Is this even possible with moment or I'll have to write some regular expression for the same. I'm sorry if My entire implementation is wrong as first time I'm using moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following sentence

moment(someDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY', true).isValid()

It will return a Boolean

Comment: this solution worked. sorry for the late reply. can you please explain why my code wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you construct the `moment`, you'd write something like this instead:

```
const myDate = moment(strDate, "MM-DD-YYYY", true)
```

where the last variable sets `strict parsing` to true (See docs here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)